# The default value of \updefault

Tags: fonts, texlive-2019

The result of the following MWE is `up` with the newest TeX Live 2019.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \updefault
\end{document}
```

Why was the default value of `\updefault` changed from `n` to `up`?

Comment: There is something about changes to the font selection mechanism in https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews31.pdf but I haven't gone through the details.

Comment: I don't find the answer in the ltnews31 or source2e:(

Comment: I didn't claim the answer was in there; that's why I posted only a comment. If I understand correctly, what formerly was `\upshape` is now `\normalshape`, which is a shorthand for `\upshape\ulcshape` (the latter being also new). You can find the changes in source2e but there is no exact explanation as why. Hopefully someone from the LaTeX team will answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the new latex `\itshape` and `\scshape` has been splitted. They can now (if the font has the shapes) be set independently. This change means that `\updefault` only describes the slant (`up`). The new command `\normalshape` can be use to reset both.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}

{ \itshape Abc \scshape  Abc \upshape Abc }

{ \itshape Abc \scshape  Abc \normalshape Abc }


\end{document}
```

### Output latex 20200202:

[image]

### Old output of the first line:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much the answer!