# What is miktex version that does not ask for any packages updates?

Tags: miktex, windows, miktex-update

So I have a problem - package updates have broken important compilation for me. I need some old MiKTeX version that can be installed and will not ask for any package updates. Where one can get such a version for windows?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. The answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/527952/2417) might be helpful, but it appears that installing the newest version and asking for help on updating your document may be an easier route.

Comment: miktex doesn't update on its own. If something was updated then because *you* clicked on some button saying "update".